# SQL Job fails with following error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a job that runs at 6am and it has been working fine up until last week...it now gives me the following error:

> Code: 0xC020200E Source: Load "123" Open "123" file Description: Cannot open the datafile "pathway/of/the/file.txt".  End Error

I checked the pathway that the error shows and the `.txt` file is missing...but no one has moved it, also I cannot see the `SSIS` packages...would granting permissions to another account fix the issue?

Comment: Is anything changed recently, any changes to permissions or  any changes to account which runs SQL agent services ?

Comment: No nothing has changed at all, it just doesn't make sense as to why it is failing when a week ago it was working...